# Feathers authentication.create throws 401 not authenticated error

Tags: node.js, feathersjs, feathers-authentication, feathers-service

// code

```
app.use('/login', {
  async create(data, params) {
    data.strategy = 'local';
    return authentication.create(data, params);
  }
});
```

// config

```
"local": {
  "usernameField": "username",
  "passwordField": "password"
}
```

I am using authentication.create method in my login API, I am getting this error response when i try to login

```
{
  "name": "NotAuthenticated",
  "message": "Invalid login",
  "code": 401,
  "className": "not-authenticated",
  "errors": {}
}
```

// request

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:3030/login'
--header 'Content-Type: application/json'
--data-raw '{
"username": "uname",
"password": "123456"
}'
```

The username and password is correct, this works in my local machine(macOS), it throws error only when i run in a testing environment(ubuntu 20 in AWS EC2). they both point to the same database(mySQL 5) inside a AWS EC2 instance. what is causing the issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mentioned in the [authentication configuration options](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/authentication/local.html#configuration) in Windows and with PM2 the `username` field needs to be escaped since it is also an environment variable:

```
"local": {
  "usernameField": "\\username",
  "passwordField": "password"
}
```

This will no longer be necessary in the upcoming version 5.